# Running ASP.NET core 2.1 microservices with ssl enabled in docker

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssl, .net-core, ssl-certificate

I'm working on a bunch of microservices in VS.NET 2017, all written in ASP.NET Core (2.1) with SSL enabled. My project is like so
- Client project (running Angular)
- API Gateway project (using Ocelot)
- Microservice
- Microservice
- Microservice
- IdentityServer4

All projects run asp.net core 2.1, and have SSL enabled using a self-signed certificate. Now All is fine, when I run everything localhost. However, if I start running stuff in containers, the certificates are starting to become a problem.

I can log in using the identityserver, bus as soon as I call the gateway microservice, it says:

> The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure

I found out the CN Name (or DNS names) of the certificate don't match the hostnames when running in docker, so I created a new certificate containing DNS names localhost, the ip of my machine, and all names of the docker containers.

There is a change, the system recognizes the 'multiple hostnames', but still the certificate isn't valid. This leaves me witht he problem that basically the microservices are just not capable of communicating with each other due to certificate problems. Does this sound familiar to someone? What can I do?

**update because of comment mjwillis**
I create a certificate with 5 dns names (localhost, the ip of my workstation, keeszapi, keeszconnect and keeszgame)
keeszapi, keeszconnect and keeszgame are the names of the docker containers and thus the hostname within the docker *network*.

Why I didn't use Let's Encrypt for example, is mainly because I just wasn't familiar with these tools.

-- Oh and wait... now I'm reading more about let's encrypt... It's not in production yet, everything is running in debug mode, that's why :)

Comment: Please share the exact URL you are unsuccessfully trying to communicate with. What happens if you try and load that URL in Chrome? Firefox? Edge?

Comment: The short answer is that your other servers don't trust your self-signed certificate (which is expected). I'd suggest investigating using Lets Encrypt certs instead.

Comment: Will look into that, thanks a bunch!